# Função para rearranjar valores em um grupo de 5 campos de um formulário, usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho 5 campos de um formulário e gostaria de, através de uma função, rearranjar os valores dos mesmos fazendo com que os primeiros campos sejam preenchidos e os últimos vazios, de acordo com os valores existentes na ordem crescente.

Por exemplo:

HTML:

```
<input id="campo1" type="text" /><br>
<input id="campo2" type="text" value="uva" /><br>
<input id="campo3" type="text" /><br>
<input id="campo4" type="text" value="laranja" /><br>
<input id="campo5" type="text" /><br>
```

Ao chamar a função, ficaria assim:

```
<input id="campo1" type="text" value="uva" /><br>
<input id="campo2" type="text" value="laranja" /><br>
<input id="campo3" type="text" /><br>
<input id="campo4" type="text" /><br>
<input id="campo5" type="text" /><br>
```

**Atualizando:** A ordem dos valores devem obedecer o `id` dos campos na ordem crescente (campo1, campo2...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#campox input'));
var valores = inputs.filter(el => el.value.trim());
inputs.forEach((el, i) => el.value = valores[i] && valores[i].value || '');
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3ormw3y/2/

Basicamente os passos são:

- coloca os inputs todos numa array
- filtra os elementos vazios
- percorre os inputs de novo usando os valores da nova array só com os inputs preenchidos

Em JavaScript ES5 poderia ser

```
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#campox input'));
var valores = inputs.filter(function(el){
    return el.value.trim();
});
inputs.forEach(function(el, i){
    el.value = valores[i] && valores[i].value || '';
});
```

Comment: Sergio, seu código tem 2 problemas: se eu mudar a "laranja" para o campo1, o resultado seria "uva, laranja"; o correto seria "laranja, uva"...  Outra coisa é que existem outros campos no formulário, e seu código seleciona todos eles, e não apenas os campos "campo1" a "campo5".

Comment: @DavidFernandes ah, então não queres ordenar os campos em ordem alfabética mas sim ordenar para não ter campos vazios no meio, é isso? Em relação aos inputs, qual é o elemento pai desses inputs? tem alguma classe específica?

Comment: Ah sim, tem uma `id` pai só para esses campos: `campox`

Comment: @DavidFernandes seria assim então: https://jsfiddle.net/x3ormw3y/2/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @DavidFernandes  Ótimo!

Comment: Sergio, agora que vi que a duas ultimas linhas não funcionam no navegador do celular. É como se desse um erro e o resto de todo o meu script que vem abaixo é ignorado. Usei o seu segundo código e nao deu erro no celular. oBG!

Comment: @DavidFernandes pois o primeiro código é JavaScript moderno (ES6) e só funciona em navegadores mais modernos.